# How to solve error factor has bad level in R

Tags: r, spatstat

I have some difficulties applying the inhomogeneous G-function to my point pattern in `R`. 
In order to use `GmultiInhom`, I first tried to convert my point pattern `bci.tree8pppa` to a multitype pattern:

```r
bci.tree8multi = ppp(bci.tree8pppa$x, bci.tree8pppa$y, window=owin(c(0,1000), c(0,500)), marks = factor(bci.tree8pppa$marks[,3]))
```

Then applied the G-function as follows:

```r
G = GmultiInhom(bci.tree8multi, marks(bci.tree8multi) == species1, marks(bci.tree8multi) == species2, lambdaI = lambda1points, lambdaJ = lambda2points, lambdamin = min(lambda2points), r = c(0,r1,r2,r3))
```

But this yields the error: `"Error in split.default(X, group) : factor has bad level"`

How can I solve this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you add a reproducible example ? That would help because here it is hard to understand your objective and the origin of the error. That would also help future users that might meet the same error

Comment: Please re-run the code that produces this error, then immediately type `traceback()` and copy the traceback output to this webpage. Also please type `summary(marks(bci.tree8multi))` and copy the output to this page.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I managed to solve it in the meantime. The problem was the vector r = c(0,r1,r2,r3)). I'm still not sure why this doesn't work, whereas r = 0:r3 does. But at least it is running now!

Comment: That's good, but could you please do the traceback anyway? Then we can figure out how this error occurred, and help other people from getting the same problem.

Comment: Also it is strongly advised (even in the help files) not to specify the argument `r`. Most people mis-use this argument. If you do specify `r`, then it should contain a large number of very closely-spaced values.

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of any `R` programmers out there: I traced the error message `"factor has bad level"` to the C source code for `.Internal(split.default(x,f))` in the base `R` system. This error message can occur only when `f` is a `list` rather than a `factor`. The code converts `f` to a factor using the function `interaction` which performs character string manipulations. This conversion can go wrong, in the sense that the resulting factor has "bad levels": the integer representation of the factor includes values less than 1 or greater than the number of levels of the factor. Then the error occurs.

The original post has not provided a working example, so it's difficult to figure out exactly how the code in `spatstat::GmultiInhom` caused the wrong type of data to be fed to `split.default`. However, it must be related to the misuse of the argument `r`. The code in `spatstat` will be tightened to enforce stricter requirements on the format of `r`.